# Convert information in a text file to a map using ArcGIS Runtime SDK?

Tags: arcgis-runtime, arcgis-runtime-sdk-java

I am new to the ArcGIS Runtime SDK. What we are trying to do is to convert information in a text file (contains country name and some information) to a map (visualize the information as a heat map for example). Do we have to convert the text file to a shapefile?

If yes, does the Runtime SDK provide API's for it or we have to go back to Engine SDK?

Answer (score 1):

No you do not need to convert your text file to a shapefile.  The ArcGIS Java Runtime SDK does not provide a tool to convert, although it does have an API to work with shapefiles.  Does the text file have geometry info, e.g. coordinates?  Essentially you can read the text file in Java then use the `GraphicsLayer` to add the graphic with geometry, symbol, attributes from the text file. If the text file is a CSV file you can use the ArcGIS Java API to work directly with it through `CSVLayer`.  How you work with the text file will depend on the format of the file, e.g. geoJSON, etc.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help, jdONeil. I did follow your suggestion and read the country information. And I did find a world map with a country property and polygons showing boundaries. The heat map can then be displayed based on the country information. However, the map is not a public one. Any one knows of a world map that can be freely accessible (with a country property and polygon boundaries)?